# How do you render Arrays entries dynamically in JSRender

Tags: jsrender

I'm using jQuery mobile and jsRender to template some JSON objects.

I have created a listview in jQuery mobile which outputs:

```
<li><a href="#product-detail" data-ID="2" data-array="0">Product A</a></li>
<li><a href="#product-detail" data-ID="5" data-array="2">Product B</a></li>
<li><a href="#product-detail" data-ID="8" data-array="3">Product C</a></li>
```

When the list link is clicked (tapped) I wish to render the product-detail page which consists of Array specific Product information and some top level JSON (language related).

```
<h2 id="h2test">{{:productArray[0].Title}}</h2>
 <div class="row">
  <div class="from-column">
   <div class="from">{{:language.products.from}}</div>
    <div class="price">£929.99</div>
   </div>
  <a href="#" class="buy-now">{{:language.products.buyNow}}</a>
</div>
```

There is a lot more to the template which includes more Array specific Product information and the language stuff.

How do I access the {{:productArray[0].Title}} dynamically? i.e. rendering a passed variable for the productArray node?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question. If you mean that you want to let the user tap/click on a product in the list, and then show the detail for that product, then it sounds like you need to use JsViews. Take a look at the [live JsViews samples](http://borismoore.github.com/jsviews/demos/index.html), and the corresponding code, including [this one](https://github.com/BorisMoore/jsviews/blob/master/demos/step-by-step/04_editable-data.html)

JsViews does data binding, allows you to change data objects and arrays 'observably', so the changes get updated automatically in rendered templates. And it allows you to get from a click event to the corresponding view object and the data item it was rendered against.